# Customising the Django Admin change password page

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to have my own custom `change_password` page and I am already using the admin login from Django(using `from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required`). 
Got the admin login working but would like to change the `change_password` page.

How do I do that?
 
I am not sure how to link to the admin login, or because I want to customize my change_password, I must customize my admin login as well?

Need some guidance. Thanks...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can import the forms

`from django.contrib.auth.views import password_change`

If you look at Django's password_change view. You will notice that it takes it a view parameters which you can supply to customise the view to your own needs thus making your webapp more DRY.

```
def password_change(request,
                    template_name='registration/password_change_form.html',
                    post_change_redirect=None,
                    password_change_form=PasswordChangeForm,
                    current_app=None, extra_context=None):
    if post_change_redirect is None:
        post_change_redirect = reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done')
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = password_change_form(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(post_change_redirect)
    else:
        form = password_change_form(user=request.user)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                            current_app=current_app)
```

Most notably, `template_name` and `extra_context` such that your view looks like this

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_change

def my_password_change(request)
        return password_change(template_name='my_template.html', extra_context={'my_var1': my_var1})
```

Answer (score 4):

Django's template finders let you override any template, in your template folder just add the admin templates you want to override, for example:

```
templates/
   admin/
      registration/
         password_change_form.html
         password_reset_complete.html
         password_reset_confirm.html
         password_reset_done.html
         password_reset_email.html
         password_reset_form.html
```

Comment: meaning to say that i should have an additional admin folder in my templates folder? did i get it correct? or edit the admin folder that django provided? btw where is the django admin folder?

Comment: it does not seem to your. I added admin templates in my app, but django still picks default admin templates.

Comment: @Pasada it might be because your app is under `django.contribute.admin` in the `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: @Gregory Goltsov thanks, your last comment helped me. :)